# GCC intrinsics alignment problems

Tags: gcc, assembly, alignment, intrinsics

I have a disturbing problem implementing a simple, non parallel average method using g++ intrinsics. Here the relevant c++ part, where p_oNumPoints is the length of the array p_pValues, which itself is a function parameter of type double*.

```
inline void arithmeticAvg (double &p_rAvg, const unsigned int p_oNumPoints, const double *p_pValues, double &p_rSum)
{
unsigned int i;
double oTmp[2] __attribute__((aligned(16))) = {0,0};

register __m128d XMM0 = _mm_setzero_pd();
register __m128d XMM1;
register __m128d XMM2;

const unsigned int oLooplength = (p_oNumPoints / 4);
for (i=0; i < (oLooplength*4); i += 4)
{
  XMM1 = _mm_loadu_pd(&p_pValues[i]);
  XMM2 = _mm_loadu_pd(&p_pValues[i+2]);
  XMM0 = _mm_add_pd(XMM0, XMM1);
  XMM0 = _mm_add_pd(XMM0, XMM2);
}
_mm_storeu_pd(oTmp, XMM0);
p_rAvg = oTmp[0] + oTmp[1];
```

gcc, using options -O2 -S -msse4.1, delivers the following assembly

```
b8b3c29e:   xorpd %xmm0,%xmm0
"b8b3c2a2:   movapd %xmm0,-0xa8(%ebp)"
b8b3c2aa:   mov 0xc(%ebp),%eax
b8b3c2ad:   shr $0x2,%eax
b8b3c2b0:   mov %eax,-0x10(%ebp)
b8b3c2b3:   movl $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)
b8b3c2ba:   jmp 0xb8b3c35c <_ZN8precitec4math13arithmeticAvgERdjPKdS1_+252>
b8b3c2bf:   mov -0xc(%ebp),%eax
b8b3c2c2:   shl $0x3,%eax
b8b3c2c5:   add 0x10(%ebp),%eax
b8b3c2c8:   mov %eax,-0x14(%ebp)
b8b3c2cb:   mov -0x14(%ebp),%eax
b8b3c2ce:   movupd (%eax),%xmm0
"b8b3c2d2:   movapd %xmm0,-0xb8(%ebp)"
b8b3c2da:   mov -0xc(%ebp),%eax
b8b3c2dd:   add $0x2,%eax
b8b3c2e0:   shl $0x3,%eax
b8b3c2e3:   add 0x10(%ebp),%eax
b8b3c2e6:   mov %eax,-0x18(%ebp)
b8b3c2e9:   mov -0x18(%ebp),%eax
b8b3c2ec:   movupd (%eax),%xmm0
b8b3c2f0:   movapd %xmm0,-0xc8(%ebp)
b8b3c2f8:   movapd -0xa8(%ebp),%xmm0
b8b3c300:   movapd %xmm0,-0x28(%ebp)
b8b3c305:   movapd -0xb8(%ebp),%xmm0
b8b3c30d:   movapd %xmm0,-0x38(%ebp)
b8b3c312:   movapd -0x38(%ebp),%xmm0
b8b3c317:   movapd -0x28(%ebp),%xmm1
b8b3c31c:   addpd %xmm1,%xmm0
b8b3c320:   movapd %xmm0,-0xa8(%ebp)
b8b3c328:   movapd -0xa8(%ebp),%xmm0
b8b3c330:   movapd %xmm0,-0x48(%ebp)
b8b3c335:   movapd -0xc8(%ebp),%xmm0
b8b3c33d:   movapd %xmm0,-0x58(%ebp)
b8b3c342:   movapd -0x58(%ebp),%xmm0
b8b3c347:   movapd -0x48(%ebp),%xmm1
b8b3c34c:   addpd %xmm1,%xmm0
b8b3c350:   movapd %xmm0,-0xa8(%ebp)
```

Despite the horrible translation of the loop-section (I tried to use the **asm("xmm")** attribute without success), this keeps crashing at the line in quotation marks. When debugging this happens when executing the _mm_setzero_pd() command, which I think is due to reordering.

VS 2010 translates this very different without crashing anything.

Any idea what the problem is and how to address the problem?

Thanks for help,
G.

Comment: please specify output of ``gcc --version`` also. I just tried with 4.7.2, generated assembler is neat and correct.

Comment: Hi, the version is 4.6.1, which I have to use due to the Momentics chaintool we are using...

Comment: Comment 2: I am most confused about the fact that the unaligned commands are sort of completely ignored...

Comment: Comment 3: I added the function definition.

Comment: gcc 4.4.5 also works fine. By the way, gcc has vector extensions, you might want to use them instead of the intrinsics, when possible.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I need to find vector commands working with both VS 2010 and g++/Momentics, and here I think the intel intrinsics are the best choice. Might you be so kind to post the assembly gcc produces and the options you use (such as -msse2...)? Thanks a lot, G.

Comment: [Here](http://ideone.com/opLov3) you go.

Comment: Thankx a lot! That is basically what I expected to get. I will close this as resolved and consider it a Momentics problem I have to deal with. Best regards, G.

Comment: After some more research, for those interested: My post is sort of a duplicate, the same issue is already dealt with. compiling with -mstackrealign helps...